# Python package structure not importing correct module

Tags: python, pip, package, pypi

Following the PYPI documentation, it shows how to install a package, which works great. But once I introduce a class to a file I can't located the class. I've attached a lot of code but i believe the context is necessary.

Now this works fine when I'm working in the directory but once its uploaded to PYPI and used elsewhere on my computer it can't find the class.

Tree

```
package_upload
├── EasyNN
│   ├── EasyNN.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── import_this.py
├── LICENSE.txt
├── README.md
└── setup.py
```

Setup.py

```
import setuptools

with open("README.md", "r", encoding="utf-8") as fh:
    long_description = fh.read()


setuptools.setup(
    name='EasyNN',
    version='0.0.3',
    description='Currently Testing',
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
    python_requires='>=3.6',
    url="https://github.com/danielwilczak101/EasyNN",
    author="Daniel",
    author_email="daniel@gmail.com",
    long_description = long_description,
    long_description_content_type = "text/markdown",
    classifier=[
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
        "License :: OSI Approved :: GNU General Public License v2 or later (GPLv2+)",
        "Operating System :: OS Independent",
        ],
    install_requires = ["matplotlib ~= 3.3.2",
                        "pytest>=3.7",
                        "tabulate >=0.8.7"
                        ],
    )
```

EasyNN.py

```
import import_this

class NN:

    def say_hello(self):
        print("Hello NN World!")
```

import_this.py

```
def foo():
    print("I've been imported")
```

Running Python Code

```
import EasyNN
nn = EasyNN.NN()
```

Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'EasyNN' has no attribute 'NN'
>>>
```

Comment: "*…preventing my python package from just installing all my files into the python package directory…*" Why? This is how it must be — all in one top-level directory. "*…cant access any my classes inside the modules…*" Please show the calling code and the error.

Comment: As you noticed yourself, you do not need the `py_modules` and `package_dir` arguments. The rest seems fine and should work perfectly fine. Maybe make sure to clean up remaining build/install artefacts before starting a new build/install.

Comment: Looks like your imports are poorly written. Do not use relative imports, they are a waste of time, unless you know exactly what you are doing. So write imports always starting from your top-level package `EasyGa`: `from EasyGa import crossover` or `import EasyGA.crossover`.

Comment: Thank you for the responses. I edited my question to simplify the question and give better context to the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to access `NN`, which lives inside of `EasyNN/EasyNN.py`. If you want to make the `NN` class available from a top-level import, you have to include it in your top-level `__init__.py` file:

```
# EasyNN/__init__.py

from EasyNN import NN
```

Then, from outside of the package, elsewhere on your computer, `NN` is now available from a top-level import.

When you import a package, you can't directly access the objects contained within the files that live inside of that package. You need to include them in your `__init__.py` of the respective package, or else access them like this:

```
from EasyNN.EasyNN import NN
```

Above, the first `EasyNN` is the package, but the second one is the **.py file** called `EasyNN` that **conatins** the class `NN`.

Comment: OMG yes!, They need this in the documentation. I would vote it up but i can't because of my peasant status. lol

Comment: @DanielWilczak Glad I could help! And lol, you *can* mark as correct answer if you feel that this answer took care of all of your questions ;)

Comment: Aww, thank you! If you want to see the fruit of your help. We used it on EasyGA python package. https://github.com/danielwilczak101/EasyGA/

Comment: @DanielWilczak woah, that's super cool. Glad I could be a part of that!